# IoTEdge module gives timeout

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have an IoTEdge module which runs a deep learning model on a Raspberry Pi 3 and runs well but then somehow returns this error:

Error: Time:Mon Jan 28 22:45:21 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2230 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK

Is this a network connection issue?  It seems afterwards, this error disappears.  Not sure why this is the case.  I thought there might be a communication error between this IoTEdge module and the IoTHub, so I even restarted the IoTEdge module and rebooted the Raspberry Pi device.

How can this be resolved?  Does it have to deal with a time.sleep(1) code in Python?

Comment: Sometimes restarting the IoTEdge module solves this problem, but not always.

Comment: I do see a lot of these messages as well in my setup. ```Error: Time:Tue Jan 29 04:42:41 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2230 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK
Error: Time:Tue Jan 29 04:42:41 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2230 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK``` can anyone from Azure IOT team respond?  I run `iotedge: 1.0.5-1` with `mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0 `

Comment: So I found out I was using azure-iothub-device-client version 1.4.3 and decided to use the latest one which is 1.4.6.  However, I still get these mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK errors.

Comment: Which version of IoT Edge are you running? Did you follow the advice here and set the OptimizeForPerformance env var to false? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux-arm#tips-and-suggestions

Comment: I do have the OptimizeForPerformance env var set to false for the edgeHub in the deployment.template.json.  Do I need to uninstall the IoTEdge and then redeploy the modules from Visual Studio Code?  I am running iotedge version 1.4.3.

Comment: Should I uninstall the IoTEdge from my device and then reinstall with the latest version and then deploy the modules?

Comment: @Rag were you able to solve this, I am still having the mqtt_client time out waiting for CONNACK errors continuing.

Comment: Hi, I run 1.0.5-1 in my env. I have not encountered the error again and I have not taken any actions since then. you may raise the issue here, https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues

Comment: @Rag what environment are you running?  Because I tried upgrading to 1.0.5-1 on my Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian and it said I had the latest one.

Comment: I am still having the same problem with this: Error: Time:Tue Feb  5 18:40:33 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c Func:InitializeConnection Line:2230 mqtt_client timed out waiting for CONNACK

Comment: @AlvinChin can you upgrade to version 1.0.6 and see if the issue is solved? See related: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/570

Comment: @AlvinChin are you still blocked? If not can you post the answer to this thread? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the original version of the Azure IoT Python SDK. This is a wrapper around the C SDK and the message you are encountering is a known bug in the C SDK. This has been fixed in the C SDK but was never propagated into the Python v1 reposiotry.

I suggest that you rebuild your Edge module using the new Python v2 SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python). By default, this is the version now used by the Visual Studio Cloud Azure Edge extension.